# Way to merge flextables and retain formatting

Tags: r, flextable

Say I have 2 flextables:

```
ft1 <- regulartable(head(iris))
ft2 <- regulartable(tail(iris))
```

And they have distinct formatting:

```
ft1 <- bg(ft1, bg="green")
ft2 <- color(ft2, color = "blue")
```

Is there a way to merge these two after they are already flextables, and keep the formatting?

I can merge them using this:

```
ft3 <- regulartable(rbind(ft1$body$dataset, ft2$body$dataset))
```

but I lose all formatting.

I understand it would be easier to merge the dataframes before converting to flextables, but the way my actual data is generated makes that difficult as the two flextables I'm trying to merge are the result of other functions I've written.

**Edit:**

The aim is to keep the individual formatting, like this:

[image]

Comment: It would require a specific development to make that possible. I will try to make it possible in the next dev run. To enable that, you need not only to merge x$body$dataset but also all formats/span  - stored in other compounds.

Comment: Cool, hopefully it can be a feature soon. thanks for always responding so quickly :)

Comment: @DavidGohel just wondering is this possible at the moment? thanks

Comment: @user63230 no, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but might get the job done...

```r
library(flextable)
library(magrittr)

ft1 <- regulartable(head(iris))
ft2 <- regulartable(tail(iris))

ft_formatting <- function(ft1, ft2,
                          color1 = "black", bg1 = "white", color2 = "black", bg2 = "white") {
  n_row1 <- nrow(ft1$body$dataset)
  n_row2 <- nrow(ft2$body$dataset)

  n_col1 <- ncol(ft1$body$dataset)
  n_col2 <- ncol(ft2$body$dataset)

  i_1 <- 1:n_row1
  i_2 <- n_row1+1:n_row2

  regulartable(rbind(ft1$body$dataset, ft2$body$dataset)) %>%
    bg(i = i_1, j = 1:5, bg = bg1) %>%
    color(i = i_1, j = 1:n_col1, color = color1) %>%
    bg(i = i_2, j = 1:5, bg = bg2) %>%
    color(i = i_2, j = 1:n_col2, color = color2)

}

ft_formatting(ft1, ft2, bg1 = "green", color2 = "blue")
```

Comment: This colours the whole thing green and makes all the text blue. Im hoping to keep the formatting the way it was in the original tables, ie, only the first 6 lines are green and the bottom 6 lines are blue. Sorry if I was unclear

Comment: yes, that will do the trick for this example, I was hoping for something a little more generic as my actual tables have heaps of formatting. Perhaps there isn't a way to make it more generic though :(

Comment: @RAB: I guess it is possible with some effort. The flextable objects have all the formatting information in them so it should be possible to extract it and then assemble a new flextable object by applying formatting on a cell by cell basis according to the flextable of origin... but maybe the package developer is better suited for this task...